# Excel - Conditional Formatting Special

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have two columns as follows:

```
1     FALSE
2     TRUE
3     FALSE
4     FALSE
5     FALSE
6     TRUE
7     FALSE
8     FALSE
```

Whenever there is a TRUE in the second column, I want to Color the first column to a certain color (RED or GREEN). What conditional formatting setting is the way to go?

Comment: Does TRUE = Green and FALSE = Red?

Comment: Apply to `$A:$A` the following formula `=$B1`

Comment: @ Scott Craner - It did not work. Can you please elaborate. I created a Conditional Formatting rule, based on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Scott Craner said in the comment, create a rule with the formula `=$B1`. It will work if you follow the instructions.

- the current cell must be in Row 1 when you create the rule
- OR, the formula must reference the same row as the current row
- AND, the column letter should be absolute (using a $ sign), while the row number MUST be relative (no $ sign).

The first two cells of the screenshot have the words typed into the cell, which turns them into booleans.

Rows 3 and 4 have start with an apostrophe, followed by the word, which makes the cell value text, not boolean

Rows 5 and 6 have a formula that returns the boolean

[image]

Comment: if that still doesn't work for you, please show your spreadsheet.